# Pygame project, screen doesn't update in one function, but it works within two other functions

Tags: python, pygame

My pygame project consists of several parts, including global map and towns. I use one Game class to contain necessary objects. All game is shown on one screen and works properly with global map and town (in_city function), it changes the screen and shows necessary information, but when I call another function (buy), it doesn't update screen.

```
def buy(self):
    while self.running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.running = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                return

        self.screen.fill('BLACK')
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip()

def in_city(self):
    while self.running:
        stop = False
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.running = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                all_sprites.update(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                button_right.click(mouse_pos)
                button_left.click(mouse_pos)
                button_next.click(mouse_pos)
                button_prev.click(mouse_pos)
                if button_close.on_button(mouse_pos):
                    stop = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self.buy()
    
        if stop:
            self.player.route = [(0, 0)]
            self.player.next_move(self.maps)
            self.camera.update(self.player)
            return

        screen.fill('WHITE')
        city.render(screen)

        current_text = city.enemies[city.current_enemy]
        window.show(screen, current_text.get_text())

        print(current_text.goods)

        all_sprites.draw(screen)


        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip()`
```

Comment: why do you call both `update` and `flip`? use only `flip`

Comment: when you have `pygame.MOUSEMOTION` or `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` then you can use `event.pos` instead of `pygame.mouse.get_pos()`

Comment: your `buy()` should display black screen - nothing more. What do you get? What do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Never run game loops recursively. Use the one application loop to draw the scene depending on states. You should never jump to another application loop in an event. The event should only change a state that is used to draw the scene. e.g.:

```py
game_state = 'A'
run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            game_state = 'B'      


    screen.fill('WHITE')

    if game_state == 'A':
        # draw scene A

    elif game_state == 'B':
        # draw scene B

    pygame.display.flip()
```